# Choose activity on Boot

Tags: android, boot

I am making an app in which i want to set my main activity i.e. on boot of phone my app should check that if there is a specific file in sdcard then it should move to another activity.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thnk that you should use flag concept:

```
if (data.contains("1"))
        {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NewClasss.class);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }
        else if (data.contains("2"))
        {

                       //list of classes  
                       // basically you have to set flag
            }
```

Comment: What to mention in  else part as my app is background app??

Comment: In if (data.contains 1) you have to write main activity and in 2 you have to mention all the activities except main activity

Answer (score 5):

Use BroadcastReceiver with boot intent.

In manifest, add:

```
  <receiver android:name=".Receiver">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

also add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Then implement class extending BroadcastReceiver, which will handle action Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED in onReceive, and do your tasks there (start service, etc).

Comment: You can also create an Activity instead of a receiver which I believe is more in line with the question.

Comment: Yes, possibly. But question was also to check presence of some file, which doesn't need Activity.

Comment: I think the best way is to create a receiver, that checks the file and based on that decides to launch the Activity and creates the proper intent.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, creating a IntentFilter listening for BOOT_COMPLETED would do the trick. 
One example: http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup